# node js reset user's password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

Goodmorning guys,
i'm implementing a NodeJs function to reset a specific user's password.
I saved all my users in a local MongoDb collection called Account with the following schema:

```
    var Account = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        unique: true,
        index: true,
        lowercase: true,
        "default": "",
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, "Please fill in your email"],
        match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, "Please fill a valid email address"]
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        "default": "",
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyPassword, "Password should be longer"]
    },
    role: {
        type: [
            {
                type: String,
                "enum": [
                    C.ROLE_SUPERADMIN,
                    C.ROLE_ADMIN,
                    C.ROLE_USER
                ]
            }
        ],
        "default": [C.ROLE_ADMIN]
    },
    registrationDate: {
        type: Date,
        "default": new Date
    }
   });
```

So, when a new user register himself in the system i save into the DB and authenticate his data using PassportJS like this:

```
// Post registration
userController.doRegister = function(req, res) {
  Account.register(new Account({username : req.body.username, password: req.body.password, role: req.body.role}), req.body.password, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      req.flash('error', 'Error: ' + err.message);
      return res.render('login/register', { roles: roles , title: 'Register'});
    }

    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
      req.session.save(function (err) {
          if (err) {
            req.flash('error', 'Error: ' + err.message);
            return next(err);
          }
          console.log("NEW USER" + "\n Email:" + req.user.username + "\n Psw: " + req.user.password + "\n Role: " + req.user.role);
          res.redirect('/login');
      });
    });
  });
};

// Post login
userController.doLogin = function(req, res, err) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); } //error exception

    // user will be set to false, if not authenticated
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('error', 'Error: ' + info.message);
      res.render('login/login', { title : 'Login'});
    } else {
        // if user authenticated maintain the session
        req.logIn(user, function() {
            // do whatever here on successful login
            req.session.save(function (err) {
              if (err) {
                req.flash('error', 'Error: ' + err.message);
                return res.render('login/login');
              }
              console.log("LOGGED IN USER" + "\n Email:" + req.user.username + "\n Psw: " + req.user.password + "\n Role: " + req.user.role);
              res.redirect('/');
          });
        })
    }    
}
)(req, res, function () {});
};
```

untill now everything goes right and works well.
I am now writing a functions to reset the password of an user, this is the method:

```
// PUT user password
panelController.resetProfile = function(req, res) {
  Account.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('error', 'Error: user not found.');
      return res.redirect('/' + req.params.redirect);
    }

    console.log("BEFORE USER: " + user.username + ' PSW: ' + user.password);
    user.password = 'admin';

    user.save(function(err) {
      req.flash('info', 'Info: ' + user.username + '\'s password has been reset to \'admin\'.');
      console.log("AFTER USER: " + user.username + ' PSW: ' + user.password);
      res.redirect('/' + req.params.redirect);
    });
  });
};
```

it works, apparently, looking to the console output and database collection. in fact. suppose that the user who we want to reset the password to 'admin' is test@test.com and his currently password is 'qwerty'. after I call that methods the console output is:

```
BEFORE USER: test@test.com PSW: $2a$10$gWNJTJW63sddcF9QGXAfKuDBmG.0S6WoH/VD4CGgC8BfyBPNvYJty
AFTER USER: test@test.com PSW: $2a$10$PULutMVzQPnShuZ5ae3T4edhvdoKKHBIwDXyQ5YfAIoONtJdQDTim
```

as you can see, the hashed-password has changed and the password field in the database has changed as well.
the problem is that, when i try to log in the system with the user test@test.com with the new password 'admin', the system gives me an error saying that the password is incorrect, morover when I try to log in with the old password 'qwerty' it lets me in. it looks like it reset the password but the system keep the old password for the match.
where im I wrong?

if you need further info please let me know, thank you!